# Attach() method for multiple tables in one function (laravel)

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent, many-to-many, laravel-5.3

I think the title is a little bit confusing so I'll try my best to explain this.

**What I have**

Car model :

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('User','car_user');
}
```

User model

```
public function cars()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Access\Car','car_user');
}
```

Reservation model

```
public function cars()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Access\Car','car_user');
}
```

Car migration :

```
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name')->nullable();
        $table->string('age')->nullable();
        $table->string('model')->nullable();
```

User migration :

```
      $table->string('street')->nullable();
        $table->string('niehgborhood')->nullable();
        $table->string('city')->nullable();
         $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name')->nullable();
```

car_user :

```
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');

        $table->integer('car_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('car_id')->references('id')->on('cars');
```

Reservation :

```
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('from_date')->nullable();
        $table->string('to_date')->nullable();

        $table->string('from_time')->nullable();
        $table->string('to_time')->nullable();
```

Controller: method to save cars and link them to user id:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
    $new_car = new Car();
    $new_car->name = $request->name;
    $new_car->age = $request->age;
    $new_car -> model = $request->model;
    $new_car->save();

    $id = $new_cars->id;
    $user->cars()->attach($id);
}
```

**What I'm trying to understand/do**

So in my Controller above I could attach user id with car id when the user wants to buy the car.

Now, can I do the same thing if the user wants to rent the car for a few hours. Say I have a form with a dropdown menu that shows some time the user wants the car. Can I save the user and the car he/she wants to rent including the time all in this function ?

Will this attach the time to the car the user interested in and be able to be called by `$user->id` to show all the cars the user either wants to buy and rent?

Thank you!

**Update**

thanks to Artur Subotkevič I now can save the id of both Cars and Reservations in car_reservation pivot table based on his answer. I tried doing this to show all cars with time associated with by this function

```
public function hour($id)
{

    $time = Car::with('reservations')->where('id',$id)->get();
    dd($time);
}
```

but I get this view

```
Collection {#364 ▼
   #items: []
```

}
I'm sure I have some cars linked to reservation and my reservation model is now

```
  public function cars()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Car','car_reservation');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this will not work correctly.

But there's a lot of ways to handle that kind of problems.

You should explain what you really want to do, and we can give you correct answer.

---

**Edit**

```
$user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();

$new_car = new Car();
$new_car->name = $request->name;
$new_car->age = $request->age;
$new_car->model = $request->model;
$new_car->save();

$time = new Reservation();
$time->from_date = $request->from_date;
$time->to_date = $request->to_date;
$time->from_time= $request->from_time;
$time->to_time = $request->to_time;
$time->save();

// Attach the reservation to the car's reservations
$new_car->Reservation()->attach($time->id);

// Attach the car to the user cars
$user->cars()->attach($new_car->id);
```

Make sure that you have set correct relationships in your Models: **you need to have Reservation relationship in your car model**.

Comment: I just edited my question , please look again at (What I'm trying to understand/do)

Comment: I think the cars and users get saved but they are not linked because I don't have car_reservation pivot table. That's why when I test it in postman it returns `"SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'injaz.car_reservation' doesn't exist`

Comment: I still cant access the time in the reservation in my controller. Can you please help ?

Comment: `public function hour($id)
    {
        $target = Car::with('reservations')->where('id',$id);

        dd($target);
    }`
doesnt return relations. my reservation mode is `public function cars()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Access\Car','car_reservation');
    }`